# how to use webmagic with GORM(grails)?

Tags: grails, web-crawler

I have to use webmagic(a web crawler framework) in my grails project, but the GORM does not work in the progress method of webmagic:

```
 @Override
public void process(Page page) {

        .........code for extraction..............


        videoAlbum.setLink(link)
        videoAlbum.setTags(tags)
        videoAlbum.setDescription(desc)

        videoAlbum.insert(failOnError: true) }
```

The insert() method does not work, and throws no error.
How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I am not aware of an explicit insert GORM method.  Don't you just want to call save(failOnError: true)?